# Implement websocket in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket

I am implementing WebSocket in chrome extension.

I wrote the code in background.js

```
var websocket;
function createWebSocketConnection() {

    if('WebSocket' in window){
        websocket = new WebSocket(host);
        console.log("======== websocket ===========", websocket);

        websocket.onopen = function() {
            websocket.send("Hello");
        };

        websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
            var received_msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
            var notificationOptions = {
                type: "basic",
                title: received_msg.title,
                message: received_msg.message,
                iconUrl: "extension-icon.png"
            }
            chrome.notifications.create("", notificationOptions);
        };

        websocket.onclose = function() { alert("==== web socket closed 
======"); };
}
```

When I open the popup screen (index.html), the method `createWebSocketConnection()` is invoked, which will create a WebSocket connection.

But as soon as the popup is closed, a message is print on the **Server console** that "**Web socket is closed**.

I have following questions-

1. Should I make WebSocket connection in content.js?
2. Do each web page opened will have different WebSocket?
3. Is there any way I can save the WebSocket object in the background.js?
4. What is the best practice of implementing web socket in chrome extensions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a same problem!
Are you found some solution?

Comment: in this example, are you able to connect to the host without using ssl?

Comment: Have you gotten answers to your 4 questions? These questions are really good but unfortunately, NO ONE has answered them yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I implemented the websockets in the `background.js`.

Following is the code:

```
function createWebSocketConnection() {
    if('WebSocket' in window){
        chrome.storage.local.get("instance", function(data) {
            connect('wss://' + data.instance + '/ws/demoPushNotifications');
        });
    }
}

//Make a websocket connection with the server.
function connect(host) {
    if (websocket === undefined) {
        websocket = new WebSocket(host);
    }

    websocket.onopen = function() {
        chrome.storage.local.get(["username"], function(data) {
            websocket.send(JSON.stringify({userLoginId: data.username}));
        });
    };

    websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var received_msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
        var demoNotificationOptions = {
            type: "basic",
            title: received_msg.subject,
            message: received_msg.message,
            iconUrl: "images/demo-icon.png"
        }
        chrome.notifications.create("", demoNotificationOptions);
        updateToolbarBadge();
    };

    //If the websocket is closed but the session is still active, create new connection again
    websocket.onclose = function() {
        websocket = undefined;
        chrome.storage.local.get(['demo_session'], function(data) {
            if (data.demo_session) {
                createWebSocketConnection();
            }
        });
    };
}

//Close the websocket connection
function closeWebSocketConnection(username) {
    if (websocket != null || websocket != undefined) {
        websocket.close();
        websocket = undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @pallavi, from answer, It seems like extension is about live notification with badge count. and I actually implementing this kind of extension for my inbox's unread message count . can you please tell me about your extension. so that I can make next flow for show live badges in extension.

Comment: can you please send me extension name. So that I can check flow of it ? It would very helpful for me. I am still finding reference extension in which real web-socket is used. Please help me

Comment: Sorry @mayurkukadiya, but that extension was developed for internal use of the organization. But I would be happy to help you.

Comment: Thank you  for reply me. which version of manifest was you used ? I am using manifest version v3 and there is no support for window object in service worker script.

Comment: @mayurkukadiya, I used "manifest_version": 2

Comment: Okay, That's why it's easy to connect with websocket. Do you have any knowledge about websocket connection with manifest v3 ?

Comment: Here is my goal what I want to accomplish : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67280321/how-to-show-realtime-data-using-web-socket-in-chrome-extension-made-with-manifes

Answer (score 14):

Hurray!

I solved this problem by modifying `manifest.json`

```
{
...
  "background": {
    ...
    "persistent": true
  },
...
}
```

Comment: What does the "persistent: true" achieve? What does it persist?

Comment: @Notflip The only occasion to keep a background script persistently active is if the extension uses chrome.webRequest API to block or modify network requests. The webRequest API is incompatible with non-persistent background pages.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what and how you want to achieve your goal.

If one persistent `WebSocket` per extension is your aim, which is the most likely scenario, then create it in the background script. Then, you can relay the messages to popup/content using [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging).

If you need to talk from the content/popup page(s) directly to the server, then create it there. When content page or popup is closed, your `WebSocket` will be closed as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want one connection pr extension. But the issue is, whenever I open the popup screen, then it, again and again, create a new WebSocket connection. 

i.e., when I open the popup, the old websocket object is lost and a new connection is established. I dont want to create new connection every time I open the popup.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way around it. Popup `window` is discarded when popup closes, therefore every `object` with it.

Comment: I believe that in content script, it wont work if third party cookies are blocked, while in background script it will.

Answer (score 1):

web socket will be closed because popup has its own context, each time you open popup its creates new object and on closing of popup, the state will be erased, you need to do this logic at background scripts! as the above developers provided some snippets!