# Listen in a websocket in Chrome extension manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

For a private extension we need to run one persistent websocket.
In manifest V2 the process was managed in the background script. But in manifest V3 the background script has been canceled in favour of service worker. Is it possible in V3 to have an ongoing process that listens to a websocket connection?

Comment: I am aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746426/implement-websocket-in-chrome-extension. But it relates to V2 which is very different in this context.

Comment: [Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618136/persistent-service-worker-in-chrome-extension/66618269#66618269), under the heading **"Forever", via a dedicated tab, while the tab is open** (probably not an ideal solution, but it should work)